# How do I create a tag synonym?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

OK, color me dumb. I found out how to view existing synonyms (Tags=>synonyms - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms ), but how do I create a **new** one?

I want to synonymize "Horcrux" and "Horcruxes" tags, since there seems to be a **constant** drift with some question getting both. I tried to merge them into Horcrux 3 times already, and new ones keep popping up.

I don't much care which of the two is the main tag and which is a synonym - merely that there aren't two, EVER again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to the [`horcrux` tag page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horcrux), click on “[synonyms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/horcrux/synonyms)”, and suggest `horcruxes` as a synonym. It takes 6 voters or a moderator to actually set the synonym, and only moderators can perform a merge (ask us on meta if there is any doubt, or in chat for no-brainer cases such as plurals).

I've set up a synonym [horcruxes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horcruxes) → [horcrux](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horcrux).

Comment: Gracci! It WAS dumb not to go to tag's individual page from the get-go :(

Comment: BTW, I was doing a merge by hand, 1 tag edit at a time. Didn't realize there was a programmatic way till today.